# List to list of tuples based on elements in list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list L = [1, 2, 3, 5n, 4, 9, 6n, 1, 3, 4, 5n].

The n present in some elements signifies the end of a grouping. Is there a way to turn this list into a list of tuples?

For example, [(1, 2, 3, 5n), (4, 5, 9, 6n), (1, 3, 4, 5n)]?

I know I can create an iterator it = iter(L), and then zip the iterator to create a list of tuples, but I can't figure out how to use the "n" flag to signal creation of a tuple.

The n is always the same and always signifies the end of a grouping. Thank you!

EDIT: All elements in the list are strings, and the output should be tuples of strings as well.

Comment: Regex matching?

Comment: Your list will not work because 5n does not present any type known to Python. It could be either ['1', '2', '3', '5n'] or [1, 2, 3, '5n'].

Comment: If these are strings, you could use `if element.endswith('n')`

Comment: All elements of the list are strings, I can change this if needed.

Comment: Create tuple until n then append tuple in new list. You did not try anything, did you?

Comment: Please edit your question because you leave your question here for posterity. So please write them as well as you would do in a blog post.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful to know what data types are for input and final output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
l =  [1, 2, 3, '5n', 4, 5, 9, '6n', 1, 3, 4, '5n']
grp = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(l, lambda x:'n' in str(x))]
[tuple(i+j) for i, j in zip(grp[::2],grp[1::2])]
#[(1, 2, 3, '5n'), (4, 5, 9, '6n'), (1, 3, 4, '5n')]
```

For your requirement in comment, I would go with loop

```
lst =  [1, 2, 3, '5n', '6n', 1, 3, 4, '5n']
l = []
l1 = []
for i in lst:
    if 'n' in str(i):
        l.append(i)
        l1.append(l)
        l = []
    else:
        l.append(i)
print (l1)
#[[1, 2, 3, '5n'], ['6n'], [1, 3, 4, '5n']]
```

Or using `re.findall` works for both your lists

```
import re
L = [1, 2, 3, '5n', 4, 5, 9, '6n', 1, 3, 4, '5n']
s = ':'.join(map(str,L))
[tuple(i.split(':')) for i in re.findall(r'([^:].*?n)', s)]
#[('1', '2', '3', '5n'), ('4', '5', '9', '6n'), ('1', '3', '4', '5n')]
```

Comment: This was actually a better answer. Follow up question: What if the list has an instance where [1, 2, 3, 5n, 6n, 7, 8, 9n]? I'd want the 6n to be in it's own tuple rather than getting added to the first tuple.

Comment: That is what I was talking about in comments. Up!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you list is following :

```
l = [1, 2, 3, '5n', 4, 9, '6n', 1, 3, 4, '5n']
[tuple(x) for x in ''.join(map(str,l)).split('n') if x]
Out[1]: [('1', '2', '3', '5'), ('4', '9', '6'), ('1', '3', '4', '5')]
```

Another way as mentioned by @Matias Cicero

```
list(map(tuple, filter(lambda x: x, ''.join(map(str, l)).split('n'))))
```

Comment: I think this is correct, but from the question it seems they want the `'n'` included in the tuple.

Comment: Yes. I think so. Waiting for him to correct the input. I am not sure what exact output he expects.

Comment: `if x!=''` => `if x`

Comment: This worked correctly, thank you! I will accept in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: If you want to stick with a functional approach, you can achieve the same thing like this: `map(tuple, filter(lambda x: x, ''.join(map(str, l)).split('n')))`

Comment: I really like this solution. OP: FYI, this won't work if the `n` is uppercased

Comment: I assume that n is a kind of delimiter which he can have as a variable instead of hardcoding. Keeping `n` so as to keep the answer short.